# Merge Project: Error while building merged project with error undefined compiler variable

Tags: install4j

I am using merge project feature of install4j.

I have created sub-project with one action in it. This action uses some compiler variables which are defined in same project(sub-project).
Now I have merged this project into main project, and created the link to an action from sub-project.
But when I try to build main project it gives error that variable used in action is not defined as shown below.

> Build failed.
>
> Cause: com.exe4j.b.z
>          When trying to process '${compiler:RegPath}': the variable 'RegPath' has not been defined. Stack trace:
>
> com.exe4j.a.d: com.exe4j.b.z: When trying to process
>   '${compiler:RegPath}': the variable 'RegPath' has not been defined.
>     at com.install4j.b.i.b(ejt:175)     at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:100)
>   Caused by: com.exe4j.b.z: When trying to process
>   '${compiler:RegPath}': the variable 'RegPath' has not been defined.
>     at com.install4j.config.l.a(ejt:577)    at
>   com.install4j.config.l.a(ejt:485)     at
>   com.install4j.config.l.a(ejt:431)     at com.install4j.b.c.f.a(ejt:84)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.f.a(ejt:87)    at com.install4j.b.c.f.a(ejt:87)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:1079)  at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:957)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:943)   at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:925)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:762)   at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:721)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.a.k(ejt:685)   at com.install4j.b.c.a.b(ejt:227)
>     at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:133)   at com.install4j.b.b.v.a(ejt:75)
>     at com.install4j.b.b.c(ejt:285)     at com.install4j.b.b.a(ejt:141)     at
>   com.install4j.b.i.a(ejt:413)  at com.install4j.b.i.b(ejt:156)     ... 1
>   more

Am I missing anything?

Project Files:  [Sub-Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PRv5Ji9O7RgG9XqQ-5T9X-qzYc7aUexF)  [Main Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bn7SUEMa95KEbsgVJ36G-Ac3ozqojjjb)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that will be fixed in 7.0.9. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.